# What's up with set -x on my system?

Tags: bash, macos, set

In trying to learn about bash shell expansion and the effects that it has on passing arguments to `grep`, someone recommended that I use `set -x` to set the trace option on my shell and see how the shell was parsing my commands. On my remote BSD account, this seems to work as expected:

```
~ $ ls
a.sh      b.sh      my.sh     small.txt temp
~ $ set -x
~ $ ls
+ ls
a.sh      b.sh      my.sh     small.txt temp
~ $ set +x
+ set +x
~ $ ls
a.sh      b.sh      my.sh     small.txt temp
~ $
```

I turn tracing on, I get an extra line of output with a + sign to denote how the shell is processing my command. (I know that I'd get more lines of output if the command were more complicated and needed more processing.) I then turn the trace off, and it goes back to its normal output So far, so good. But, when I do the exact same command on my local terminal running bash on the Mac in Mojave, I get an entirely different output:

```
~ $ ls
#hello#         Downloads/      Public/         isus/
#two#           Library/        Sync/           notes.txt
Applications/       Movies/         bin/            notes.txt~
Desktop/        Music/          derby.log       sync-startup-log.txt
Documents/      Pictures/       hello~
~ $ set -x
++ update_terminal_cwd
++ local url_path=
++ local i ch hexch LC_CTYPE=C LC_ALL=
++ (( i = 0 ))
++ (( i < 12 ))
++ ch=/
++ [[ / =~ [/._~A-Za-z0-9-] ]]
++ url_path+=/
++ (( ++i ))
++ (( i < 12 ))
++ ch=U
++ [[ U =~ [/._~A-Za-z0-9-] ]]
++ url_path+=U
++ (( ++i ))
++ (( i < 12 ))
++ ch=s
++ [[ s =~ [/._~A-Za-z0-9-] ]]
++ url_path+=s
++ (( ++i ))
++ (( i < 12 ))
++ ch=e
++ [[ e =~ [/._~A-Za-z0-9-] ]]
++ url_path+=e
++ (( ++i ))
++ (( i < 12 ))
++ ch=r
++ [[ r =~ [/._~A-Za-z0-9-] ]]
++ url_path+=r
++ (( ++i ))
++ (( i < 12 ))
++ ch=s
++ [[ s =~ [/._~A-Za-z0-9-] ]]
++ url_path+=s
++ (( ++i ))
++ (( i < 12 ))
++ ch=/
++ [[ / =~ [/._~A-Za-z0-9-] ]]
++ url_path+=/
++ (( ++i ))
++ (( i < 12 ))
++ ch=a
++ [[ a =~ [/._~A-Za-z0-9-] ]]
++ url_path+=a
++ (( ++i ))
++ (( i < 12 ))
++ ch=d
++ [[ d =~ [/._~A-Za-z0-9-] ]]
++ url_path+=d
++ (( ++i ))
++ (( i < 12 ))
++ ch=m
++ [[ m =~ [/._~A-Za-z0-9-] ]]
++ url_path+=m
++ (( ++i ))
++ (( i < 12 ))
++ ch=i
++ [[ i =~ [/._~A-Za-z0-9-] ]]
++ url_path+=i
++ (( ++i ))
++ (( i < 12 ))
++ ch=n
++ [[ n =~ [/._~A-Za-z0-9-] ]]
++ url_path+=n
++ (( ++i ))
++ (( i < 12 ))
++ printf '\e]7;%s\a' file://admins-iMac.local/Users/admin
~ $ ls
+ ls -F
#hello#         Downloads/      Public/         isus/
#two#           Library/        Sync/           notes.txt
Applications/       Movies/         bin/            notes.txt~
Desktop/        Music/          derby.log       sync-startup-log.txt
Documents/      Pictures/       hello~
++ update_terminal_cwd
++ local url_path=
++ local i ch hexch LC_CTYPE=C LC_ALL=
++ (( i = 0 ))
++ (( i < 12 ))
++ ch=/
++ [[ / =~ [/._~A-Za-z0-9-] ]]
++ url_path+=/
++ (( ++i ))
++ (( i < 12 ))
++ ch=U
++ [[ U =~ [/._~A-Za-z0-9-] ]]
++ url_path+=U
++ (( ++i ))
++ (( i < 12 ))
++ ch=s
++ [[ s =~ [/._~A-Za-z0-9-] ]]
++ url_path+=s
++ (( ++i ))
++ (( i < 12 ))
++ ch=e
++ [[ e =~ [/._~A-Za-z0-9-] ]]
++ url_path+=e
++ (( ++i ))
++ (( i < 12 ))
++ ch=r
++ [[ r =~ [/._~A-Za-z0-9-] ]]
++ url_path+=r
++ (( ++i ))
++ (( i < 12 ))
++ ch=s
++ [[ s =~ [/._~A-Za-z0-9-] ]]
++ url_path+=s
++ (( ++i ))
++ (( i < 12 ))
++ ch=/
++ [[ / =~ [/._~A-Za-z0-9-] ]]
++ url_path+=/
++ (( ++i ))
++ (( i < 12 ))
++ ch=a
++ [[ a =~ [/._~A-Za-z0-9-] ]]
++ url_path+=a
++ (( ++i ))
++ (( i < 12 ))
++ ch=d
++ [[ d =~ [/._~A-Za-z0-9-] ]]
++ url_path+=d
++ (( ++i ))
++ (( i < 12 ))
++ ch=m
++ [[ m =~ [/._~A-Za-z0-9-] ]]
++ url_path+=m
++ (( ++i ))
++ (( i < 12 ))
++ ch=i
++ [[ i =~ [/._~A-Za-z0-9-] ]]
++ url_path+=i
++ (( ++i ))
++ (( i < 12 ))
++ ch=n
++ [[ n =~ [/._~A-Za-z0-9-] ]]
++ url_path+=n
++ (( ++i ))
++ (( i < 12 ))
++ printf '\e]7;%s\a' file://admins-iMac.local/Users/admin
~ $ set +x
+ set +x
~ $ ls
#hello#         Downloads/      Public/         isus/
#two#           Library/        Sync/           notes.txt
Applications/       Movies/         bin/            notes.txt~
Desktop/        Music/          derby.log       sync-startup-log.txt
Documents/      Pictures/       hello~
~ $
```

Any idea what's going on here? Is this normal? It's as if the system is adding these commands/lines of script after every command that I do. Does it have something to do with using Terminal on the Mac? Or is there some weird bash configuration on my system that I haven't been able to track down?

Any way to turn this off? I'd like to have a more useful function of `set -x` when I use it. This just makes it impossible to try to understand how the shell is parsing commands.
Thanks.

Comment: Is there a `PROMPT_COMMAND` set in the shell?

Comment: This is what I have set:
    `$ echo $PROMPT_COMMAND`
    `update_terminal_cwd`
    ` ~ $`

Comment: OK so I guess you are seeing the inner workings of that function (you should be able to display it using `declare -f -p update_terminal_cwd`)

Comment: set -x is useful in scripts for debug purposes. I never saw it used on the command line before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer over at Ask Different:

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/238736/why-does-set-x-cause-the-terminal-to-dump-garbage/376906#376906

I can use the advice over there to turn this off when I want, and turn it back on when I'm done. Seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

That happens if `PS1` and / or `PROMPT_COMMAND` contains a command.

Answer (score 0):

Usually happens when `PROMPT_COMAND` or `PS1`. The usual workaround is:

```
set -x;   ls;   set +x
```

That is: surround the command with the trace commands.